# Cant start tomcat with spring boot on linux

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suddenly I cant start my embedded tomcat.

I get:

```
[main] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-86"]
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

I tried changing tomcat port,
I tried setting permissions:  chmod 777 src/ -R

I use linux Mint 17

I have no idea what to do...

This is the stacktrace:

```
    [main] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-86"]
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:647) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:459) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.company.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,609 [main] ERROR o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-86]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-86]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898) [spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.company.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1014) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:647) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,609 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-86"]
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,609 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-86"]
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,609 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,612 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,612 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,612 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,613 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
- 2014-10-30 10:30:51,613 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at com.company.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:102)
    ... 12 more
```

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a local tomcat installation or do you run tomcat via mvn tomcat7:run?

Comment: I dont know but it is embedded with spring boot so I think it uses mvn.
I don't run a tomcat on my own and I don't use eclipse to start and stop it.

Answer (score 37):

Linux doesn't allow a normal user to bind to a TCP port that's <= 1024. There's a discussion of the reasons for that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only). You're attempting to bind to 86 and, therefore, it's failing with "Permission denied". The quickest and safest solution is to configure the port with a value that's > 1024.

As you're using Boot's embedded Tomcat instance, the port's configured in `application.properties` using the `server.port` property.