# I can't start tomcat 7 server on linux openshift - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-12345"]

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, openshift, url-mapping

I've checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648344/cant-start-tomcat-with-spring-boot-on-linux?newreg=82b5b5ff2c264b8992ff1b24045b51c8) question which is very similar to mine, however the difference is **I'm using a port > 1024 (i.e. I'm using port 12345)** which is what the answerer said to do. I'm trying to run a Tomcat instance on an Openshift server.. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

### My execution script is as follows:

```
nohup java -Xms384m -Xmx412m -jar target/*.war --server.port=12345
```

Note the "-jar" is this right? I am deploying a .war file not a .jar? I think.. Sorry, a little new to this.

## The important part of my error output is as follows:

> 2015-10-07 19:30:13.317  INFO 261765 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX
>   exposure on startup 2015-10-07 19:30:13.409 DEBUG 261765 --- [
>   main] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Looking for resource
>   handler mappings 2015-10-07 19:30:13.411 DEBUG 261765 --- [
>   main] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource
>   handler mapping: URL pattern="/**/favicon.ico", locations=[class path
>   resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/],
>   class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class
>   path resource []],
>   resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@f5e53a1]
>   2015-10-07 19:30:13.412 DEBUG 261765 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler
>   mapping: URL pattern="/webjars/**", locations=[class path resource
>   [META-INF/resources/webjars/]],
>   resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@1f5137b7]
>   2015-10-07 19:30:13.414 DEBUG 261765 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler
>   mapping: URL pattern="/**", locations=[ServletContext resource [/],
>   class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource
>   [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource
>   [public/]],
>   resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3f8892d1]
>   2015-10-07 19:30:14.022 ERROR 261765 --- [           main]
>   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point
>   associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-12345"]
>
> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:653)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186)
>     at  ...

## application.properties:

> logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
>
> logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
>
> error.whitelabel.enabled=false
>
> server.port=12345

## web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Demo Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <!--<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>-->
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

## mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

And finally...

## Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping ("/isRunning")
    boolean isRunning () {
        return true;
    }

    @RequestMapping ("/")
    String home () {
        return "Home";
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        System.out.println("RUNNING! :D");
    }
}
```

And finally...

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-crud-with-vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## UPDATE 1

Okay, so I ran rhc app-tidy -a {APP_NAME} and it now deploys fine and launched and works fine but I am still having the same error log output... Why is this? What's wrong?

> 2015-10-08 03:15:41.254 ERROR 290379 --- [           main]
>   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point
>   associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>
> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:653)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
>     at hello.Application.main(Application.java:41)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 2015-10-08 03:15:41.263 ERROR 290379 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector
>   [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8080]]
>
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8080]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
>     at hello.Application.main(Application.java:41)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat"; 
>   Protocol handler start failed     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 18 common frames omitted Caused by: java.net.SocketException:
>   Permission denied     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:653)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007)
>     ... 19 common frames omitted
>
> 2015-10-08 03:15:41.347  INFO 290379 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2015-10-08 03:15:41.682  INFO 290379 --- [           main]
>   .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start
>   with classpath:
>   [file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-jdbc-7.0.59.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli-7.0.59.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-log4j-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib/h2-1.4.188.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib-provided/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.59.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.59.jar!/,
>   jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/5612fdaa89f5cfa2090000dd/app-root/runtime/repo/target/gs-crud-with-vaadin-0.1.0.war!/WEB-INF/lib-provided/tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.59.jar!/]
>   2015-10-08 03:15:41.683  INFO 290379 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report enable debug logging (start with --debug)
>
> 2015-10-08 03:15:41.724 ERROR 290379 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
>     at hello.Application.main(Application.java:41)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 2015-10-08 03:15:41.724  INFO 290379 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7c2b6a03:
>   startup date [Thu Oct 08 03:14:59 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   2015-10-08 03:15:41.739  INFO 290379 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans on shutdown 2015-10-08 03:15:41.777  INFO 290379 --- [
>   main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
>     at hello.Application.main(Application.java:41)  ... 6 more Starting
>   jbossews cartridge Found 127.7.143.1:8080 listening port Archiving
>   artifacts Unable to auto-install JDK until the license is accepted.
>   Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: While you mention the problem in your title, it's a bit confusing when you don't write it out in the actual text of the question.  In other words, something like this: "I'm attempting to X.  But when I Y, Z happens/doesn't happen."

Comment: Only the root can bind to low-numbered ports.

Comment: @bmargulies yes, I understand, but I'm not binding to a low numbered port am I? I'm binding to port 12345.

Comment: @neanderslob I'm sorry my question wasn't in the format you wanted. I assumed it was obvious that I can not start my server. So I'm sorry, here's my question in your format: **"I am attempting to start my server. But when I try to start my server, the error output happens."**

Comment: @JoshuaKing much better; just trying to help you start out right. :-)

Comment: @neanderslob Alright, awesome thanks! But why would my question be downvoted?

Comment: @JoshuaKing Unfortunately there are some in the community who will do a drive-by down vote without taking the time to tell the user what they would like to see improved.  I've been on S/O off and on for a couple years now and it still can make me cranky for the rest of the day if someone does that to me :-P

Comment: @neanderslob Oh, well that's awful... Okay, well thanks for your help! :D

Comment: @JoshuaKing I would definitely extract some of the logs to an external paste site like pastebin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the exception that was being thrown should have been a StupidDeveloperException. Anyway, I had already started tomcat on that port and wasn't stopping it before trying to bind it again to the same port, resulting in that error. Thanks guys for all your input!

Answer (score 1):

As [described here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Binding_Applications_to_Ports.html), OpenShift restricts the ports that an application can bind to. You can use 15000 - 35530 to bind an internal IP. You can also use 8080, and must do so if you want your Spring Boot app to be externally accessible.

You also need to bind to the correct address. There's an example showing how to configure the address and port using OpenShift's environment variables in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cloud-deployment-openshift.html):

```
nohup java -jar target/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} &
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but I also tried 8080 but to no avail. With same error output

Comment: I tried it again with `8080` and it says `Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`