# Spring boot application wont start in openshift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I created openshift project with DIY cartridge, added postresql for DB.. now I pushed sources to cloud, but I'm getting error like the guy here (but he was not using springboot): [I can't start tomcat 7 server on linux openshift - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-12345"]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004769/i-cant-start-tomcat-7-server-on-linux-openshift-failed-to-start-end-point-ass)

```
Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler
```

It's obvious that if I run the app twice the error message 'Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler' appears. I tried rhc app-tidy, restarted APP via openshift interface, i made change, pushed to cloud, build success, but the message appeared again. How to stop the app so that I can run it properly? Didn't the app being stopped after the restart I performed?

UPDATE: Have I chosen the right steps? (with DIY cartridge), do You have a simple (& working) guide how to deploy such an app to openshift? I tried few I found over the net, but none of them worked :(

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you after someone answers :).
I also tried a lot, but wasn't able to deploy. So I switched to Heroku and Pivotal CF, they are much easier.

Comment: Sure, I'll be trying again after easters because I need to make this work.

Comment: What is other technology you are using? Are you using mvc, jsf, REST etc? You could deploy sb using DIY.

Comment: Spring boot and spring data (hibernate),postgresql, mvc and security. It is the same behaviour like if you run the app localy, and then you try to run it again without stopping previous instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is steps I follow using DIY cartridge, hope this would help

1. Go to home directory of project perform following tasks
2. Create Settings.xml and refer maven repo by updating settings.xml as shown in following xml snippet below. And also add the file to git repo

   ```
   <settings>
       <localRepository>${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/m2/repository</localRepository>
   </settings>
   ```
3. Got to `.openshift` directory and delete all the files except `action_hooks`
4. Go to `action_hooks` and perform following task
     
     i.    Delete `README.md`
     
     ii.   Create deploy file (note the file extension while create should not be txt) and add following code snippet
                   (It basically creates and downloads and sets up java8 and maven

   ```
               #!/bin/bash
               set -x
               if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/m2/repository ]
               then
                       cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
                       mkdir m2/repository                
               fi
               if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_51 ]
               then
                   cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
                   wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u77-b03/jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz
                   tar xvf *.tar.gz
                   rm -f *.tar.gz
               fi

               if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.3 ]
               then
                   cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
                   wget http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
                   tar xvf *.tar.gz
                   rm -f *.tar.gz
               fi

               cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
               export M2=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
               export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms500m -Xmx500m"
               export JAVA_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_51
               export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2:$PATH

               mvn -s settings.xml clean install
   ```

iii.    Add the deploy file to git 

            iv. Edit `start` file with following snippet.

```
            #!/bin/bash
            source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH
            set -x
            export JAVA_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jdk1.8.0_51
            export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
            cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
            nohup java –Xms500m –Xmx500m -jar target/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} &
```

v.  Edit stop with following code snippet

```
            #!/bin/bash
            source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH
            PID=$(ps -ef | grep java.*\.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')
            if [ -z "$PID" ]
            then
                client_result "Application is already stopped"
            else
                kill $PID
            fi
```

vi. Make deploy file executable (Note: This is very important and its common mistake, if not executable your project will not start)

6. Commit the changes along with your maven `src` and `pom.xml` your application should automatically start once the commit is done,  
   **Note:** for first time it will take time as it needs to download maven repo.
7. For debuging purpose, its better to add logback.xml in your class path(`src/main/resources`)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/kp-apps.log" />
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
      <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" />
   ```

Comment: Regarding point vi: Make deploy file executable - how to do that? it should be a hook called 'deploy' like the start and stop is, what do you mean by make it executable? Anyway thanks for the guide, I'll try it today and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Its linux execute property chmod 777 gives read-write-execute permission for all.. The file perission must be executable

Comment: So in order to start the application I had to remove JVM parameters at starting jar (start hook), but after I did it the same error appeared :( as before

Comment: But it is not necessary to set java and maven manually since it is there by default (and Im ok with java7)

Comment: Make sure you are starting tomcat in OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT and IP, address, Openshift assigns different port and ip address, the ip address is not 127.0.0.1(localhost). and also while stop hook, please make sure, you stop the application. Here I'm killing the process, but you can make use of actuator and shutdown REST api

Comment: I tried to use your hooks so yes I am starting tomcat with that port and IP. But I do not need to stop the app if I am pushing it first time to the cloud, do I?

Comment: Yes, you should not stop the app

Comment: But as I wrote, I push first time and it fails

Comment: Please check if your previous instance of tomcat is running, if so stop that, Btw I was refering to Cartridge.